# Is there a way to configure git for synapse using terraform or arm templates?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

'''

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "example" {
  name                                 = "example"
  resource_group_name                  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = data.azurerm_storage_container.example
  sql_administrator_login              = "sqladminuser"
  sql_administrator_login_password     = "admin@123"

  azure_devops_repo {
      account_name = "organizationaz440"
      branch_name = "Development"
      project_name = "TestProject"
      repository_name = "DataOps"
      root_folder = "/SynapseNew"
      tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  }
  depends_on = [resource.azurerm_synapse_workspace.example]
}
```

'''

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/synapse_workspace

Error: Blocks of type "azure_devops_repo" are not expected here.

Comment: Which version of terraform are you using?

Comment: Hi Fedor, I am using Terraform v1.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things which needs to be fixed:

> 1. You are giving `storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = data.azurerm_storage_container.example` instead you have to give
>    `storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.id`. You have to
>    create a datalake gen 2 filesystem using your exisitng storage
>    account as data source for `azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem` is not supported.
> 2. You can remove this `tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id` as its optional and
>    keeping it will give an error that `An argument named "tenant_id" is not expected here.`
> 3. You can remove `depends_on = [resource.azurerm_synapse_workspace.example]` as its not required.

**So, after the above changes are made the .tf file will be like below:**

```
    provider "azurerm" {
        features{}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_storage_account" "name" {
      name = "ansumanstorageacc"
      resource_group_name = "yourresourcegroupname"
    }
    resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
      name               = "example"
      storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.name.id
    }
    resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "example" {
      name                                 = "example"
      resource_group_name                  = "yourresourcegroupname"
      location                             = "West US 2"
      storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem_id = azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.example.id
      sql_administrator_login              = "sqladminuser"
      sql_administrator_login_password     = "admin@123"
    
      azure_devops_repo {
          account_name = "organizationaz440"
          branch_name = "Development"
          project_name = "TestProject"
          repository_name = "DataOps"
          root_folder = "/SynapseNew"
      }
    }
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

**terraform apply -auto-approve:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. On executing terraform apply -auto-approve the code is returning below mention error.
Error: Unsupported block type
Blocks of type "azure_devops_repo" are not expected here.

Comment: @SANDEEPKUMAR, I am able to do the terraform apply -auto-approve, for the same code I have provided in the answer . added the image of the operation as well.

Comment: Thank you for your continuous support @AnsumanBal-MT. The issue is resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up you azure_devops_repo inside azurerm_synapse_workspace as follow:

```
azure_devops_repo = [{
      account_name = "organizationaz440"
      branch_name = "Development"
      project_name = "TestProject"
      repository_name = "DataOps"
      root_folder = "/SynapseNew"
      tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
}]
```

Basically, as list of object.

Comment: I am yet facing an error.

Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on ..\..\Modules\Synapse\main.tf line 38, in resource "azurerm_synapse_workspace" "example":
│   38:   azure_devops_repo = [{
│
│ An argument named "azure_devops_repo" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "azure_devops_repo"?